# Mongoose get document as an array of arrays based on a key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't really know how to frame the question but what I have is the following schema in mongoose

```
new Schema({

                        gatewayId: { type: String, index: true },
                        timestamp: { type: Date, index: true },
                        curr_property:Number,
                        curr_property_cost:Number,
                        day_property:Number,
                        day_property_cost: Number,
                        curr_solar_generating: Number,
                        curr_solar_export:Number,
                        day_solar_generated:Number,
                        day_solar_export:Number,
                        curr_chan1:Number,
                        curr_chan2:Number,
                        curr_chan3:Number,
                        day_chan1:Number,
                        day_chan2:Number,
                        day_chan3:Number
},{
    collection: 'owlelecmonitor'
});
```

and I want to be able to query all the documents in the collection but the data should be arranged inside the array in the following format

```
[ [{
    gatewayId: 1,
    timestamp: time
    ....
   },
   {

    gatewayId: 1,
    timestamp: time2
    ....
   }],
  [{
    gatewayId: 2,
    timestamp: time
    ....
   },
   {

    gatewayId: 2,
    timestamp: time2
    ....

   }],
  [{
    gatewayId: 3,
    timestamp: time
    ....

   },
   {

    gatewayId: 3,
    timestamp: time2
    ....

   }] 
];
```

Is there a way that I can do this in mongoose instead of retrieving the documents and processing them again ?

Comment: Besides the extra array, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Consider the following aggregation pipeline in mongo shell. This uses a single pipeline stream comprising of just the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator, grouping all the documents by gatewayId and creating another array field that holds all the grouped documents. This extra field uses the accumulator operator **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** on the system variable **[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables)** which returns the root document, i.e. the top-level document, currently being processed in the aggregation pipeline stage.

With the **[`cursor`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#cursor-behavior)** returned from the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** method, you can then use its **[`map()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor.map)** method to create the desired final array. The following mongo shell demonstration describes the above concept:

```
var result = db.owlelecmonitor.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$gatewayId",
            "doc": {
                "$push": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    }
]).map(function (res){ return res.doc; });
printjson(result);
```

This will output to shell the desired result.

To implement this in Mongoose, use the following aggregation pipeline **[builder](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-group)**:

```
OwlelecMonitorModel
    .aggregate()
    .group({
        "_id": "$gatewayId",
        "doc": {
            "$push": "$$ROOT"
        }        
    })
    .exec(function (err, result) {
        var res = result.map(function (r){return r.doc;});
        console.log(res);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.

Comment: @Bazinga777 No worries, happy to help :)